# Is it always possible to prove a divisibility question using combinatorial argument?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

Is it always possible to prove a divisibility question using combinatorial argument?

By 'divisibilty question', I am referring to the questions like-

Proving that $ \frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}$ is an integer.

So my question is, is it always possible to make a combinatorial argument for any given expression?( if that expression is indeed an integer).

Comment: "*is it always possible*"... even if it were, that doesn't necessarily mean it is easy or obvious.  Consider also how negative numbers come into play in questions like these which often don't have any clean combinatorial interpretation.  Proving that $\frac{2\cdot 3^n-10\cdot 7^n}{8}$ is an integer might not necessarily have a clean combinatorial proof.  Yes... there is some subset of base $7$ numbers where each of which are a multiple of 8 of that size after flipping sign...but describing what that set actually looks like and correctly counting it may be *much* harder than an induction proof.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I agree. Combinatorial argument may not always be the easiest way to prove divisibility all the time, but I'm asking whether it is always possible to construct such an argument or not. How to prove or disprove that ?

Comment: From a moral standpoint, I have to say no.  From a technical standpoint, I have to say yes, however for many problems such proofs could be *incredibly* contrived and generally useless... The strength and beauty of proving things from a combinatorial argument come when the objects you are counting lend themselves to things which are *conveniently* and *frequently* counted...

Comment: In order to "prove" such a statement, you'd need to have an unambiguous definition of  exactly which arguments are Combinatorial and which are not. Obviously, some arguments are intuitively combinatorial and some others aren't, but that intuition is not enough to prove something about all arguments.